# wget recursive folder/file download only returns multiple index.html

Tags: command-line, download, wget, recursive

```
wget --no-parent --recursive --level=4 https://www.example.com/jsons/
```

I'm using the above line to try & download all files in subfolders of that URL.

The folder structure is as:

```
https://www.example.com/jsons/XX/(multiple files)
```

where 'XX' is various two digit folder names.

It is downloading all the folders but only downloading the index.html file into each of those folders. None of the other files (.json in this example) is downloaded.

If I specifically specify one of those 'XX' folders it downloads all the files including .json for that folder, as expected.

```
wget --no-parent --recursive --level=4 https://www.example.com/jsons/BS/
```

Using 1.21.4 & running it in a Windows cmd window.

This is a (snip) of the verbose output by wget for an individual folder:

> --2023-07-05 20:23:52--  https://www.example.com/jsons/BL/ Reusing existing connection to [www.example.com:443](http://www.example.com:443). HTTP request sent,
> awaiting response... 200 OK Length: unspecified [text/html] Saving to:
> 'www.example.com/jsons/BL/index.html'
>
> [www.example.com/jsons](http://www.example.com/jsons)     [ <=>                   ]   8.95K  --.-KB/s
> in 0.001s

Any ideas?